# Move-SPSite and the Recycle Bin

Tags: recycle-bin

I have just moved a SharePoint 2019 site collection sitting by itself on a database using the Move-SPSite command to another database. Everything seemed to go well but then I noticed the new database was significantly smaller than the original database. After searching around I noted Recycle Bins were empty.  Just wondering if not copying the content of recycling bins is a feature or a bug of Move-SPsite?